# E-commerce-like solution

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

I've been asked to build a website that is basically like a web-store, but without the need to sell products, what I mean by this is, the client wants to keep track and let visitors know of his product's stock, be able to catalog the store's products and other store like features. We're talking heavy machinery here, so there's no interest in making the product available to buy right away as some products require customer specifications that are different for everyone, thus making online buying unpractical.

What I came here for is, based on this, what do you recommend? I can use a template or a plugin, I would rather use free stuff even if they require more work because I didn't give a high price for the website, I want to use WordPress because I like it so much and I'm used to working with it, I doubt you'll point me in another direction since this is a WordPress answers Q&A, but I'm open to other platforms if you have well built arguments as to why it is better than WordPress.

This is my first online store in this terms, I have worked with Magento, and for the type of shop this requires, I think it just isn't worth the trouble of going through a whole Magento web-store, what do you think?

I'm looking into Woocommerce, it seems like the best option and its free and has translation files, that should be useful, do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to have a product catalog, with no option for purchase at this stage, and are looking to potentially have the option for visitors to purchase via the online store at a later date, I'd recommend using [WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) along with the [Catalog Visibility Options](http://www.woothemes.com/products/catalog-visibility-options/) extension.

This enables you to disable the purchase functionality, until you're ready to integrate online sales, as well as display a message such as "Call for price" in it's place.

All the best with this venture.

Comment: yes, that's what i want, this catalog visibility extension, since it's a woocommerce extension, im assuming it is also translatable, right? its important that even after an update things remain translated because my client wants full control of the website after it is done, so, i wouldnt want to mess with the plugin files directly